# Rails 5 post file with Rest Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I am trying to post a file in multipart data, from my server to an external server.

I am trying to perfect this action, when arriving on a page, so with the page controller for the action of this page:

```
Def page

    RestClient::Request.execute('https://.......', :file => File.new("app/assets/file/28000JAM20.344", 'rb'), headers={:type => 'file',
            :size => 40, :name => 'contact'})

end
```

So far i cannot manage to get anything posted, what I am missing?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the method param and setting it as POST as described here https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client? also show the log output for when you try to send that samje request to your own site when you are testing it so we can see what is being received by that call

Comment: I have tried this as well:

     def page
 
     require 'rest-client'


    RestClient::Resource.new(
    url,
    :verify_ssl =>  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
    ).post(:fichero => File.new(@filep, 'rb'), :params => {type: "file", size:    40})

    end


But no post is performed, i was looking in the network tools of firefox and in my logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the **Def** keyword is always in small letters. Now lets talk about problem you have not specified the request type. According to me it must be post request type. So try the below solution

```
    def page
        request = RestClient::Request.new(
                :method => :post,
                :url => 'https://.......'
                :payload => {
                :multipart => true,
                :file => File.new("app/assets/file/28000JAM20.344", 'rb')
              })
        response = request.execute
    end
```

Comment: I've try that as well, and i get an error:  
    unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Comment: I have updated my answer please go through it. Also, you are getting a syntax error not any standard error

Comment: Adding  :verify_ssl =>  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE make the trick.

Comment: And if you need header, place it after payload: Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
  def page
    require 'rest-client'
    @filep = 'yourfilepath'

    request = RestClient::Request.new(
            :method => :post,
            :verify_ssl =>  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
            :url => 'your url',
            :payload => {
            :multipart => true,
            :file => File.new(@filep, 'rb')
          },
            :headers => {:type => 'file', :size => 40, :name => 'myfile'}
          )
    response = request.execute

  end
```